# Trap bash errors from child script

Tags: bash, bash-trap

I am calling a bash script (say `child.sh`) within my bash script (say `parent.sh`), and I would like have the errors in the script (`child.sh`) trapped in my parent script (`parent.sh`).

I read through the [medium article](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/the-bash-trap-trap-ce6083f36700) and the [stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282722/is-trap-inherited-by-a-subshell). Based on that I thought I should do `set -E` on my parent script so that the TRAPS are inherited by sub shell. Accordingly my code is as follows

**parent.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
  
set -E

error() {
  echo -e "$0: \e[0;33mERROR: The Zero Touch Provisioning script failed while running the command $BASH_COMMAND at line $BASH_LINENO.\e[0m" >&2
  exit 1
}

trap error ERR
./child.sh
```

**child.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -al > /dev/null
cd non_exisiting_dir #To simulate error
echo "$0: I am still continuing after error"
```

**Output**

```
./child.sh: line 5: cd: non_exisiting_dir: No such file or directory
./child.sh: I am still continuing after error
```

Can you please let me know what am missing so that I can inherit the TRAPs defined in the parent script.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, on a linux bash shell. If you are on a different environment, add it into the question.

Comment: I tried this in one of the EC2 instances. `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release ` is my bash version.

Comment: @VivekMaran : If you want `child.sh` to abort on commands yielding a non-zero exit code, you could simply do a `set -e`.

Answer (score 4):

`./child.sh` does not run in a "subshell".

A subshell is not a child process of your shell which happens to be a shell, too, but a special environment where the commands from inside `(...)`, `$(...)` or `...|...` are run in, which is usually implemented by forking the current shell *without* executing another shell.

If you want to run `child.sh` in a subshell, then *source* that script from a subshell you can create with `(...)`:

```
(. ./child.sh)
```

which will inherit your `ERR` trap because of `set -E`.

Notes:

There are other places where bash runs the commands in a subshell: process substitutions (`<(...)`), coprocesses, the `command_not_found_handle` function, etc.

In some shells (but not in bash) the leftmost command from a pipeline is not run in a subshell. For instance `ksh -c ':|a=2; echo $a'` will print 2. Also, not all shells implement subshells by forking a separate process.

Even if bash [infamously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) allows functions to be exported to other bash scripts via the environment (with `export -f funcname`), that's AFAIK not possible with traps ;-)